# Creating a table on Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

```
CREATE TABLE DowJones (quarter int, stock string, StockDate date, open double, high double, low double, close double, volume double, percent_change_price double, percent_change_volume_over_last_wk double, previous_weeks_volume double, next_weeks_open double,  next_weeks_close double, percent_change_next_weeks_price double, days_to_next_dividend int, percent_return_next_dividend double) row format delimited fields terminated by ‘,’;
```

**Error I get:**

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:431 mismatched input ',' expecting StringLiteral near 'by' in table row format's field separator [ERROR_STATUS]
```

New to SQL, so apologies in advance if it's a really obvious fix.

Comment: not sure if it is just copy/paste wrong format but it looks like the statement ends with wrong apostrophes? can you try and replace it with normal apostrophes ‘,’

Comment: You're correct. I copied and pasted from elsewhere - Changed the apostrophes and now the query works - Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: error in ‘,’ I think it is due to copy/paste. Replace and write again

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
row format delimited fields terminated by '\;'
```

Let us know

Comment: I haven't tried this, but what "mcha" suggested by replacing the apostrophes worked - Thanks for your help!